# Network don't recognize Printer's Scanner "Ricoh"

Tags: networking, printing, scanner

I have a "Ricoh Aficio MP 2851" Printer/scanner/fax all in one used on top of a my home router.

On Windows, it works fine using TWAIN.

On Ubuntu 20.04:

- The printer is found automatically.
- The scanner doesn't appear on the network!

How to make the network recognize it?

I tried to search for it using these but none did it:

- Simple Scan
- sane-pygtk
- xSane

[image: Add Printer, Printer, Simple Scan, sane-pygtk & xSane]